# serialport responding to EventHandler, but not ReadExisting or ReadLine?

Tags: c#, serial-port

i have a program that's reading from serial port in c#.  i need to quickly write to a port, read from it, then close it.  i cannot leave it open.  i understand that serial ports read and write slowly, I've tried to set the ReadTimeout and WriteTimeout properties high, and added a thread.Sleep to try to drag the read and write times out for the devices.  here's a little bit of code:

my method to write to port:

```
    private void CheckPorts(string testMessage)
    {

        foreach (string s in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
        {
            portNumber = Int32.Parse(s.Remove(0, 3));
            testSerial = new SerialPort(s, baudRate, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            if (testSerial.IsOpen)
            {
                testSerial.Close();
            }
            testSerial.ReadTimeout = 2000;
            testSerial.WriteTimeout = 1000;
            testSerial.Open();
            if (testSerial.IsOpen)
            {
                string received;
                testSerial.DiscardInBuffer();
                try
                {
                    //testSerial.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(testSerialPort_DataReceived);

                    testSerial.Write(testMessage);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

                    received = testSerial.ReadExisting();  //EITHER I USE THIS OR EVENT HANDLER, NOT BOTH
                }
                catch (TimeoutException e)
                {
                    testSerial.Close();
                    continue;
                }

               if (received.Length > 0)
                {
                    MessageReceived(received);
                }
                testSerial.Close();
            }
       } 
 }



 private void testSerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string received = testSerial.ReadExisting();
        int y = received.IndexOf("\r");
        while (y == -1)
        {
            received = received + testSerial.ReadExisting();
            y = received.IndexOf("\r");
        }

        if (testSerial.IsOpen)
        {
            testSerial.Close();
        }

    }
```

i'm wondering, if i absolutely have to use datahandler, how do i keep the serial port open long enough to read from it, but close the serialport before the next port needs to be opened?

see, the first method gets called a few times, and it iterates through a foreach loop, trying a message on a few ports, then trying to read a response.  so, at some point i have to close the ports, or else the next time it goes through it, it doesn't work properly because the port is still open

HERE'S MY UPDATED CODE (still not working):

```
 private void CheckPorts(string testMessage, int baudRate)
    {

        foreach (string s in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
        {
            var interval = 3000; // ms 
            var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(interval);
            timer.Elapsed += (o, e) =>
            {
                timer.Enabled = false;

                if (testSerial.IsOpen)
                    testSerial.Close();  // may not be necessary with Dispose? 

                testSerial.Dispose();
                timer.Dispose();
            };

            portNumber = Int32.Parse(s.Remove(0, 3));
            testSerial = new SerialPort(s, baudRate, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            testSerial.ReadTimeout = 2000;
            testSerial.WriteTimeout = 2000;
            if (testSerial.IsOpen)
            {
                testSerial.Close();
            }

            testSerial.Open();
            timer.Enabled = true; 

            if (testSerial.IsOpen)
            {
                string received;
                //testSerial.DiscardInBuffer();
                //autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
                try
                {
                   // testSerial.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(testSerialPort_DataReceived);

                  // autoEvent.Reset();
                    lblPortNum.Content = s;
                    lblPortNum.Refresh();

                    testSerial.Write(testMessage);
                    //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

                    //testSerial.NewLine = "\r\n";
                    byte[] rBuff = new byte[2];
                    int rCnt = testSerial.Read(rBuff, 0, 2);
                    System.Text.Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
                    received = enc.GetString(rBuff);



                     //received = testSerial.ReadLine();
                }
                catch (TimeoutException e)
                {
                    testSerial.Close();
                    continue;
                }

               if (received.Length > 0)
               {
                    MessageReceived(received, Int16.Parse(s.Remove(0, 3)));
                }
                /*
                if (autoEvent.WaitOne(2000))
                {
                    // the port responded 
                   // testSerial.Close();
                    autoEvent.Dispose();
                    lblPortNum.Content = "HEY I RESPONDED";
                }
                else
                {
                    testSerial.Close();
                    autoEvent.Dispose();
                    continue;
                    // port did not respond within 2 seconds 
                }*/
              //testSerial.Close();
            }
        } 
     }
```

UPDATED AGAIN (still not working properly)

```
private void CheckPorts(string testMessage, int baudRate)
    {

        foreach (string s in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
        {
            portNumber = Int32.Parse(s.Remove(0, 3));

            // MUST BE LOCAL 
            var serialOneOfMany = new SerialPort(s, baudRate, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            serialOneOfMany.ReadTimeout = 2000;
            serialOneOfMany.WriteTimeout = 2000;
            if (serialOneOfMany.IsOpen)
            {
                serialOneOfMany.Close();
            }

            // timer must be defined _after_ serialOneOfMany 
            var interval = 3000; // ms  
            var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(interval);
            timer.Elapsed += (o, e) =>
            {
                timer.Enabled = false;

                if (serialOneOfMany.IsOpen)
                    serialOneOfMany.Close();  // may not be necessary with Dispose?  

                serialOneOfMany.Dispose();
                timer.Dispose();
            };

            if (serialOneOfMany.IsOpen)
            {
                string received;

                try
                {
                    lblPortNum.Content = s;
                    lblPortNum.Refresh();

                    serialOneOfMany.Write(testMessage);
                    byte[] rBuff = new byte[2];
                    int rCnt = serialOneOfMany.Read(rBuff, 0, 2);
                    System.Text.Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
                    received = enc.GetString(rBuff);

                }
                catch (TimeoutException e)
                {
                    serialOneOfMany.Close();
                    continue;
                }

                if (received.Length > 0)
                {
                    CheckIfTheMessageMatches(received, Int16.Parse(s.Remove(0, 3)));
                }

            }
        } 

    }
```

so with this update, it just blows through the code, i can step through the code line by line, but it doesn't stop for 3 seconds at all.  if i run it without any debugging breaks, it just goes through it i a fraction of a second

UPDATE 10-25-11

```
 private void CheckPorts(string testMessage, int baudRate)
    {
        foreach (string s in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
        {
            string received = "";
            testSerial = new SerialPort(s,baudRate, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

            lblStatus.Content = "Scanning...";
            lblStatus.Refresh();

            if (testSerial.IsOpen)
            {
                testSerial.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                testSerial.Open();
            }

            if (testSerial.IsOpen)
            {
                try
                {
                    testSerial.NewLine = "\r";
                    lblPortNum.Content = s;
                    lblPortNum.Refresh();
                    testSerial.WriteTimeout= 500;
                    testSerial.ReadTimeout = 1000;
                    testSerial.WriteLine(testMessage);

                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

                    /*THIS DOESN'T WORK
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[testSerial.BytesToRead];
                    int rCnt = testSerial.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    received = enc.GetString(buffer);*/

                    //received = Convert.ToString(testSerial.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)buffer.Length));


                    received =  testSerial.ReadLine();


                   int y = received.IndexOf("\r");
                   while (y == -1)
                   {
                       received = received + testSerial.ReadExisting();
                       y = received.Length;
                   }

                   if (lblInfo.Dispatcher.Thread == Thread.CurrentThread)
                   {
                       CheckIfTheMessageMatches(received, s);
                       received = received + lblInfo.Content;
                       lblInfo.Content = received;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       lblInfo.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new ThreadCheck(threadCheck), received);
                   }
                   if (testSerial.IsOpen)
                   {
                       testSerial.Close();
                   }

                    /*I USE THIS WITH THE sPort.Read() METHOD
                    while (rCnt > 0)
                    {
                        if (lblInfo.Dispatcher.Thread == Thread.CurrentThread)
                        {
                            CheckIfTheMessageMatches(received, s);
                            rCnt = 0;
                            received = received + lblInfo.Content;
                            lblInfo.Content = received;                                
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            lblInfo.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new ThreadCheck(threadCheck), received);
                        }
                    }
                     */

                   if (testSerial.IsOpen)
                   {
                       testSerial.Close();
                   }

                }
                catch (TimeoutException e)
                {
                    testSerial.Close();
                    continue;
                }
                received = null;
            }
        } 

        lblStatus.Content = "Finished Scanning.";
        lblPortNum.Content = "";
    }
```

UPDATED CODE
here's some new code, still not working, dataeventhandler not even called once.  i know it's getting messages because i have another program that works with the serial devices

```
private void CheckPorts(string testMessage, int baudRate)
    {
        foreach (string s in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
        {
            var serialOneOfMany = new SerialPort(s, baudRate, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            serialOneOfMany.ReadTimeout = 700;
            serialOneOfMany.WriteTimeout = 100;

            var interval = 500; // ms
            var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(interval);
            timer.Elapsed += (o, e) =>
            {
                timer.Enabled = false;

                if (serialOneOfMany.IsOpen)
                    serialOneOfMany.Close();  // may not be necessary with Dispose?

                serialOneOfMany.Dispose();
                timer.Dispose();
            };
            timer.Enabled = true;

            lblStatus.Content = "Scanning...";
            lblStatus.Refresh();

            if (serialOneOfMany.IsOpen)
            {
                serialOneOfMany.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                serialOneOfMany.Open();
            }

            if (serialOneOfMany.IsOpen)
            {
                string received;

                try
                {
                    lblPortNum.Content = s;
                    lblPortNum.Refresh();

                    serialOneOfMany.WriteLine(testMessage);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(400);
                    serialOneOfMany.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(testSerialPort_DataReceived);

                }
                catch (TimeoutException e)
                {
                    serialOneOfMany.Close();
                    continue;
                }
            }
        } 

        lblStatus.Content = "Finished Scanning.";
        lblPortNum.Content = "";
    }

    private void testSerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort receivingSerial = sender as SerialPort;
        string received = receivingSerial.ReadExisting();
        int y = received.IndexOf("\r");
        while (y == -1)
        {
            received = received + receivingSerial.ReadExisting();
            y = received.IndexOf("\r");
        }

        if (lblInfo.Dispatcher.Thread == Thread.CurrentThread)
        {
            string name = receivingSerial.PortName;
            received = received + lblInfo.Content;
            lblInfo.Content = received;
            CheckIfTheMessageMatches(received, name);
        }
        else
        {
            lblInfo.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new ThreadCheck(threadCheck), received);
        } 
        if (receivingSerial.IsOpen)
        {
            receivingSerial.Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: What happens when you use ReadExisting? The TimeoutException is rised?

Comment: actually nothing happens.  when i put a breakpoint there, it doesn't read any value.  but it works in the eventhandler

Comment: actually when i put a breakpoint at the messagereceived method.  because it doens't call that method unless a reponse is received

Comment: Can you explain to me why you can't leave the serial port "open"? What functional requirement must this code cover within your application?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do these simultaneously (assuming that's ok).  You would then close them as the `DataReceived` event is raised (extraneous code removed).  Just don't close the port in `CheckPorts`.

```
private void testSerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort localSerialPort = sender as SerialPort;

    ... // use localSerialPort instead of global/class variable

    if (localSerialPort.IsOpen)
    {
        localSerialPort.Close();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:  Responding to comment.

You can always add a timer on the fly.  If you put this in the foreach loop, you'll get a timer for every serial port that will dispose its given serial port after 3 seconds.  It's important here that the timer is declared within the foreach loop.

```
var interval = 3000; // ms
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(interval);
timer.Elapsed += (o,e) => 
    {
        timer.Enabled = false;

        if (testSerial.IsOpen)
            testSerial.Close();  // may not be necessary with Dispose?

        testSerial.Dispose();
        timer.Dispose();
    }

timer.Enabled = true;
```

**EDIT**:  Code updated so I'll update

Scope is very important with the code I provided.  You should get rid of the non-local testSerial or use an entirely different name here.

```
        portNumber = Int32.Parse(s.Remove(0, 3));

        // MUST BE LOCAL
        var serialOneOfMany = new SerialPort(s, baudRate, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        serialOneOfMany.ReadTimeout = 2000;
        serialOneOfMany.WriteTimeout = 2000;
        if (serialOneOfMany.IsOpen)
        {
            serialOneOfMany.Close();
        }

        // timer must be defined _after_ serialOneOfMany
        var interval = 3000; // ms 
        var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(interval);
        timer.Elapsed += (o, e) =>
        {
            timer.Enabled = false;

            if (serialOneOfMany.IsOpen)
                serialOneOfMany.Close();  // may not be necessary with Dispose? 

            serialOneOfMany.Dispose();
            timer.Dispose();
        };
```

Comment: but if i iterate through a port that doesn't respond at all, then it doesn't get closed at all, and that's the problem.  i need some sort of method that closes the port when if ReadTimeout occurs, if there's nobody at the door when it knocks

Comment: i tried both above.  the if i assign a new value such as localserialport, it doesn't work.  and i tried other one (which i think is the best route), but as soon as i try writing to the port, it says it's closed.  i define it in the beginning of the method, and add timer.enabled as soon as i call testSerial.Open.  am i putting those in the right places?

Comment: @darthwillard:  You'd have to post your latest implementation to get advice on placement.

Comment: @darthwillard:  You're never re-opening the serial port nor enabling the timer...

Comment: where do i stick the timer.enable = true?

Comment: @darthwillard:  After you open the connection for your test.

Answer (score 1):

Check this info from Microsoft:

> This method returns the contents of the stream and internal buffer of the SerialPort object as a string. This method does not use a time-out. Note that this method can leave trailing lead bytes in the internal buffer, which makes the BytesToRead value greater than zero.

Why don't use the usual Read method `SerialPort.Read (Byte[], Int32, Int32)`

Comment: aside from msdn definition of serialport.read, i can't find an example of using that that returns characters as a string. is there an example somewhere? also, does serialport.read wait for the buffer to fill up before returning that method? because i'm only looking for 1 or 2 characters on each port

Comment: nevermind, i got it to work.  still doesn't work for me the way i want it.  thanks though.

Comment: Sure. To create a string from a byte array just use System.Text.ASCII.GetString(bytearray)

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this (I also used in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911001/serialport-and-dispatchertimer-how-to-make-my-thread-pause-when-com-port-is-ope/7912091#7912091) to a serial port related question asked by darthwillard).  All the ports are opened one after another, the DataReceived events are bound (all you need to do there is to test the incoming message), but no waiting is required.  The timer event handler can close all the ports or keep the one you want to use etc.  I hope it helps!

```
private List<SerialPort> openPorts = new List<SerialPort>();

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int baudRate = 9600;
    string testMessage = "test";
    txtPortName.Text = "Testing all serial ports";
    foreach (string s in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
    {
        SerialPort newPort = new SerialPort(s, baudRate, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        if (!newPort.IsOpen)
        {
            try
            {
                newPort.Open();
            }
            catch { }
        }
        if (newPort.IsOpen)
        {
            openPorts.Add(newPort);
            newPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialOneOfMany_DataReceived);
            newPort.Write(testMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            newPort.Dispose();
        }
    }
    txtPortName.Text = "Waiting for response";
    tmrPortTest.Enabled = true;
}

private void serialOneOfMany_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    txtPortName.Text = ((SerialPort)sender).PortName;
}

private void tmrPortTest_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tmrPortTest.Enabled = false;
    foreach (SerialPort port in openPorts)
    {
        if (port.PortName != txtPortName.Text)
        {
            port.Close();
            port.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your event handler before you write to the port, and then see if it doesn't catch your break point.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Thread.Sleep. It blocks the read from the device. You need to spawn a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

You may be best with [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). Eg:

```
        BackgroundWorker worker=new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += (s, dwe) =>
                             {
        // do your serial IO here
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, rwe) =>
        {
            // check for rwe.Error and respond
        };
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Answer (score -1):

open the port in public form1
just after/below the InitializeComponent(); myport.open
and close the after data is received.
worked!